# Division gives the wrong value

Tags: excel, vba

Guys this is driving me crazy!
 I'm trying to divide two cells and the the answer is always 1.
Look at the picture to understand more about the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAUxV.jpg
As you can see, I'm using the correct sheet number.

The variable "PTDPE" was not used in the code before.
I don't really want to bother you guys with the code since it is about 600 lines, but If you need it I can add it here.

```
Dim PTDPE As Integer

PTDPE = Sheets(2).Cells(17, 6).Value / Sheets(2).Cells(17, 7).Value

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(17, 8).Value = PTDPE
```

The other variables are alright and give the correct value.  but this one is always showing 1

Comment: Given the answer, you should check all your other variables to make sure that they are capable of holding the expected results at that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `PTDPE As Integer`.  When excel performs the division it rounds the result to the nearest `Integer` - in this case 1.

Change your decaration to `Dim PTDPE As Single`

Comment: Double would be better than Single, to match Excel's internal number precision

Comment: @CharlesWilliams but Single is more compact in memory and is the next closest type to Integer.